# Exporting org to pdf: LaTeXerror

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export, pdf

When I try to export a `.org` or `.tex` file to pdf with the command `org-latex-export-to-pdf`, I get the following error in `*Messages*` buffer:

```
Processing LaTeX file ./test.tex...
org-latex-compile: PDF file ./test.pdf wasn't produced: [LaTeX error]
```

I couldn't find anymore debug info. I already tried to install `texlive-core` and `texlive-bin` package from archlinux repo, but it didn't help.

EDIT: After digging further into the problem, I saw that org runs the command `pdflatex file.tex`, and it returned it couldn't find the file `utf8x.def`

Comment: The Q and A do not help anyone as currently written, unless some more info is added. Voting to close, until/unless that happens.

Comment: @Drew I edited the question and answer with the exact error, if you still think it won't help anyone I'll also vote to close. Thanks

Comment: Can you run the `pdflatex` command from the command line and tell us if you get the same error?  If yes, then it's a latex problem.  If no, then it's presumably related to your Emacs setup.

Comment: @Dan, running `pdflatex` now works, so yes, it's a latex issue. But emacs doesn't tell me that, and in my search I couldn't find any help with the error returned by emacs, so I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @Jesse: the reason I ask is that, if it's not actually Emacs related, the question makes more sense on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dan I still think the incomplete debug info that emacs returns makes this emacs related... anyway, should I vote to close this question then?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you asked the question in bad faith, but only that you would be more likely to get more tex-specific answers on the tex sister site (although it's a moot point here because you figured it out yourself).  As for closing the question: let's see what the peanut gallery does with it.

Comment: @Jesse, the incompleteness is in your error message, not emacs. Emacs logs all messages, including pdflatex errors. Look in log files in the folder where the pdf is being generated. Look in tex error logs. Emacs will have a file name of such logs.

Comment: @Jessie: The LaTeX PDF export should log its output to a buffer called "`*Org PDF LaTeX Output*`". If that exists, try switching to it with `C-x b`. (Or does that not exist when you export?)

Comment: I see. Should I vote for closing or deleting?

Comment: FWIW, I found this answer very helpful as I was trying to get org-mode to export a pdf. Also, I didn't know to look for the *Org PDF LaTeX Output* buffer; thanks for that tip as well.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the package `texlive-latex-extra`, that contains the `utf8x.def` file, fixed this issue for me.
So for Debian based machines `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` should do it.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was exactly. If not, then the question and answer should perhaps be deleted, as they cannot really help anyone. IOW, try to edit your answer and/or question to provide something that might help others. Otherwise, I think the question should be closed.